# How is QStyle.StandardPixmap defined in PyQt6

Tags: python, enums, pyqt, pyqt6

How is the enumeration for QStyle.StandardPixmap defined in PyQt6? I've tried to replicate it as shown below:

```
from enum import Enum

class bootlegPixmap(Enum):
    SP_TitleBarMenuButton = 0
    SP_TitleBarMinButton = 1
    SP_TitleBarMaxButton = 2

for y in bootlegPixmap:
    print(y)
```

I get the following output:

```
bootlegPixmap.SP_TitleBarMenuButton
bootlegPixmap.SP_TitleBarMinButton
bootlegPixmap.SP_TitleBarMaxButton
```

If I try and iterate over the original using the following code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QStyle
for x in QStyle.StandardPixmap:
    print(x)
```

I get numerical values only:

```
0
1
2
...
```

Comment: Since there is no python source, just weird SIP files, I had to check the `.whl`: defined as `class StandardPixmap(enum.IntEnum): ...`, which means it behaves like an `int`. Not really sure since it is only `QtWidgets.pyi` ype hints, code seems to be binary in `QtWidgets.abi3.so`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with PyQt *per se*. It's just the normal behaviour of Python's [enum classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum).

By default, the members of `IntEnum/IntFlag` print their *numerical* values; so if you want more informative output, you should use `repr` instead:

```
>>> import enum
>>>
>>> class X(enum.IntEnum): A = 1
...
>>> f'{X.A} - {X.A!r}'
1 - <X.A: 1>
```

By contrast, the members of `Enum` have opaque values, so they default to a *textual* representation of the values:

```
>>> class Y(enum.Enum): A = 1
...
>>> f'{Y.A} - {Y.A!r}'
Y.A - <Y.A: 1>
```

Needless to say, PyQt always uses the integer classes, since that's closest to how they're defined in Qt:

```
>>> from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QStyle
>>>
>>> QStyle.StandardPixmap.mro()
[<enum 'StandardPixmap'>, <enum 'IntEnum'>, <class 'int'>, <enum 'ReprEnum'>, <enum 'Enum'>, <class 'object'>]
>>>
>>> f'{QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_ArrowUp} - {QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_ArrowUp!r}'
>>> '50 - <StandardPixmap.SP_ArrowUp: 50>'
```